# numpy and pytables issue (error: tuple index out of range)

Tags: python, numpy, pytables

I am new to python and pytables. Currently I am writing a project about clustering and KNN algorithm. That is what I have got.

****************       code      *******************************

```
import numpy.random as npr
import numpy as np
```

## step0: obtain the cluster

```
dtype = np.dtype('f4')

pnts_inds = np.arange(100)
npr.shuffle(pnts_inds)
pnts_inds = pnts_inds[:10]
pnts_inds = np.sort(pnts_inds)
for i,ind in enumerate(pnts_inds):
    clusters[i] = pnts_obj[ind]
```

## step1: save the result to a HDF5 file called clst_fn.h5

```
filters = tables.Filters(complevel = 1, complib = 'zlib')
clst_fobj = tables.openFile('clst_fn.h5', 'w')  
clst_obj = clst_fobj.createCArray(clst_fobj.root, 'clusters',
           tables.Atom.from_dtype(dtype), clusters.shape,
           filters = filters)
clst_obj[:] = clusters
clst_fobj.close()
```

## step2: other function

blabla

## step3: load the cluster from clst_fn

```
pnts_fobj= tables.openFile('clst_fn.h5','r')
for pnts in pnts_fobj.walkNodes('/', classname = 'Array'):
    break
```

#

## step4: evoke another function (called knn). The function input argument is the data from pnts. I have checked the knn function individually. This function works well if the input is pnts  = npr.rand(100,128)

```
def knn(pnts):
    pnts = numpy.ascontiguousarray(pnts)
    N = ctypes.c_uint(pnts.shape[0])
    D = ctypes.c_uint(pnts.shape[1])
```

#

## evoke knn using the cluster from clst_fn (see step 3)

```
knn(pnts)
```

****************   end of code   *******************************

My problem now is that python is giving me a hard time by showing:
error: IndexError: tuple index out of range
This error comes from 
"D = ctypes.c_uint(pnts.shape[1])"   this line.

Obviously, there must be something wrong with the input argument. Any thought about fixing the problem? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Looks like `pnts` is 1-dimensional.  Right before the offending line, add `print repr(pnts)` and `print repr(pnts.shape)`.

Comment: im sorry ...I, in fact , made some silly mistakes by showing different results. Now I find out the problem, and it starts working..  Thank you so much @DSM